# Remove folder from git by wildcard

Tags: git, gitignore

If you have software that automatically creates folders like:

```
images/user1
images/user2
images/user3
```

What can I put in the .gitignore file to insure that they are not stored in the repo?  I have tried:

```
images/user*/
images/user*/.jpg
images/user*
```

But none of these are working as desired.  I do not want any of the dynamically created folders stored in git.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `images/user*/*` ? or `images/user**/*`

make sure you miss out trailing white space also